# inline if else statement in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I run the below code

```
iostat -x 1 2 | sed 's/,/./g' | awk '/^avg-cpu/        {c++; a=2} 
                c==2 && a && !--a {printf ("%s,%s,%s,", $1, $3, $4)} 
                c==2 && /^sda/    {printf ("%s,", $14)}
                c==2 && /^sdb/    {printf ("%s,", $14)}
                c==2 && /^nvme0n1/    {printf ("%s,",$14)}'
```

in order to get the values of cpu and disk i/o. What I'm now trying to do is a check if there is nvm disk or not. If there is print its util otherwise print -1.00.

I tried

```
if [ c==2 && /^nvme0n1/ ] then {printf ("%s,",$14)}; else {printf -1.00}'
```

and I'm getting

```
awk: cmd. line:5:                        if [ c==2 && /^nvme0n1/ ] then {printf ("%s,",$14)}; else {printf -1}
awk: cmd. line:5:                        ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:5:                        if [ c==2 && /^nvme0n1/ ] then {printf ("%s,",$14)}; else {printf -1}
awk: cmd. line:5:                                                ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:5:                        if [ c==2 && /^nvme0n1/ ] then {printf ("%s,",$14)}; else {printf -1}
awk: cmd. line:5:                                                                             ^ syntax error
```

and

```
c==2 && !/^nvme0n1/ {printf ("%s,",1.00)}'
```

which gives me more than one 1.00, I guess each 1.00 for each time cannot find it.

Unfortunately, I got no help from ShellCheck
[image]

Comment: It should be `[ c==2 && /^nvme0n1/ ]` Note the space around `[` and `]`. Post your full error message.

Comment: There are multiple problems with your code, so please run it through shellcheck.net to fix the more easily correctible ones before asking why it doesn't work.

Comment: @chepner it's not duplication because its not  the spaces.

Comment: Duplication was the fastest way to close a question that was both too broad and showed little research effort (since you clearly did not use shellcheck.net, as suggested in the `bash` tag wiki, before posting).

Comment: I'm sorry @chepner but I think my question is not too broad. I have a code which runs and I'm trying to add an if - else statement. Obviously, I cannot do it that's why I'm asking for help. If you don't want to help it's ok. Don't underestimate my question though.

Comment: you're trying `bash` syntax inside `awk` script!  Replace square brackets with regular ones.

Comment: Is your question "how do I extract disk throughput from iostat, or `-1` if not available?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to get the disk throughput utilization or `-1` is not available with `awk`.

`awk` is its own, separate scripting language, and you can't use any `bash` syntax in it.

The main issue, though, is that there is no way to determine whether or not you've found your number until you've read all lines. Once you've processed all the lines, you can determine whether to print a number or `-1`. You can use awk's special `END` block for that. This code additionally uses the special `BEGIN` block to set the default value:

```
iostat -x 1 2 | sed 's/,/./g' | awk '
            BEGIN {
              disk = -1;
            }
            /^avg-cpu/        {c++; a=2}
            c==2 && a && !--a {printf ("%s,%s,%s,", $1, $3, $4)}
            c==2 && /^sda/    { disk=$14;}
            c==2 && /^sdb/    { disk=$14; }
            c==2 && /^nvme0n1/    { disk=$14; }
            END {
              printf("%s", disk);
            }
        '
```